# Calling assemby code from C wiping out address after multiple calls

Tags: c, assembly

ASSEMBLY

```
TITLE   adding numbers
.486
.MODEL      FLAT,C
option      casemap:none
include     C:\Users\Thao\Hello\msvcrt.inc
.data
formating  DB "%s",10,0
           DB 0
num1       DB "0000000000"
           DB 0

num2       DB "0000000000"
           DB 0

AC_balance DB "0000000000"
           DB 0


.code

adding      PROC C, number1:DWORD , number2:DWORD

            mov esi, number1
            lea edi, num1 
            mov ecx, SIZEOF num2
            rep movsb 
            mov     eax, offset num1

            push    eax

            mov     eax, OFFSET formating
            push    eax
            call    printf
            pop     eax
            pop     eax
;---------------------------------------------------            

            mov esi, number2
            lea edi, num2 
            mov ecx, SIZEOF num2
            rep movsb 

            mov     eax, OFFSET num2
            push    eax

            mov     eax, OFFSET formating
            push    eax
            call    printf
            pop     eax
            pop     eax


            mov esi,SIZEOF num1-1
            mov edi,SIZEOF num1-1
            mov ecx,SIZEOF num1
            mov bh,0            ;used to save carry value


            L1: mov ah,0            ;clear AH before the add
            mov al,num1[esi]    ;get a digit
            add al,bh               ;add previous carry (0 first time through)
            aaa                     ; adjust the total
            mov bh,ah               ; save the carry in BH
            or  bh,30h              ;convert carry to ASCII character

            add al, num2[esi]   ;perform main add
            aaa                     ; adjust the main add, AH gets the carry
            or  bh,ah               ; combine the carries
            or  bh,30h              ; convert back to ASCII
            or  al,30h              ; convert digit back to ascii
            mov num2[edi],al    ;save total digit

            dec     esi             ;move left 1 digit in addends
            dec     edi             ;move left 1 digit in result
            loop    L1

            mov eax, offset num2
            push eax

            mov eax, offset formating
            push eax
            call printf
            pop eax
            pop eax

            mov eax, offset num2

            ret
adding      ENDP
END
```

C code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *adding(char *y,char *x);
void _tmain(void)
{
    char *a, *b, *a1, *b1;
    int z = 6;
    int sizeA =9;
    int sizeB =9;
    a = (char*)malloc(11*sizeof(char));
    b = (char*)malloc(11*sizeof(char));
    a1 = (char*)malloc(11*sizeof(char));
    b1 = (char*)malloc(11*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(a, "0000000000");
    strcpy(b, "0000000001");
    strcpy(a1, "3234567890");   
    strcpy(b1, "1234567890");

    printf("adding A\n");
    a=adding(a1,a);
    printf("a: %s\n",a);
    printf("adding B\n");
    b=adding(b1,b);
    printf("a: %s\n",a);
    printf("b: %s\n",b);
    getchar();
}
```

OUTPUT currently

```
adding A
3234567890
0000000000
a: 3234567890
adding B
1234567890
0000000001
a: 1234567891
b: 1234567891
```

Well I'm at a road block since now for some reason I'm whipping out addresses, when I'm debugging in visual studio I notice that the addresses seems be written over I guess. And I'm not sure why and how its getting written over. By the end of the runs A and B are pointing to the same thing. I'm not sure what to do at this point at all..

I know it has something to do with my assembly code.. but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong though. Does it have something to do with the stack?

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
a = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
b = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
a = "0000000000";
b = "0000000001";
```

to:

```
a = malloc(11);
b = malloc(11);
strcpy(a, "0000000000");
strcpy(b, "0000000001");
```

(you'll also need to add `#include <string.h>`)

Comment: Well you should at least fix this part, since currently you're allocating memory, then changing the pointers to point at read-only string literals (leaving the malloc'd memory orphaned), which is both pointless and potentially buggy.

Comment: Yea that true, a little strain with assembly and forgetting basic.

Comment: You should probably just allocate and initialise `a` and `b` in the same way that you currently allocate/initialise `a1`/`b1`.

Comment: K I modified it to keep it consistent

Comment: I realize something if I keep calling my assembly function will it constantly wipe out the register its using?

Comment: You need to save and restore registers according to whatever ABI you are using. I'm guessing this is Windows so you'll need to follow the Windows ABI calling conventions for non-volatile registers.

Comment: Oh Okay I think I finally get what I'm suppose to do.